# Не маппятся данные с объекта

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, crud

Можете помочь новичку?:) Собственно Задача реализовать CRUD. Не хотят маппиться записи в таблицу. В контроллере лист не пустой, вывел их в консоль. 
Controller.java:

```
import com.Crud.CrudController.model.Book;
import com.Crud.CrudController.service.BookService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


import java.util.Map;


@Controller
public class BooksController {
private final BookService bookService;

@Autowired(required = true)
public BooksController(@Qualifier(value = "BookService") BookService 
bookService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listBooks(Map<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("book", new Book());
    map.put("listBooks", bookService.listBooks());
    map.put("book", bookService.listBooks().get(0));
    map.put("books", bookService.listBooks());
    System.out.println(bookService.listBooks().get(0).toString());
   return "books";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/books/add")
public String addBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book) {
    if (book.getId() == 0)
    bookService.addBook(book);
   return "books";
}
}
```

books.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%--<%@ taglib prefix="from" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" 
%>--%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%--<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>--%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Books</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>1Books:</h1>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Isbn</th>
<th>PrintYear</th>
<th>ReadAlready</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
    <form:form action="books" method="POST" commandName="book"/>
<%--<c:forEach items="${listBooks}" var="b">--%>
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${book.id}"/></td>
    <td>${book.title}</td>
    <td><c:out value="${book.description}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${book.author}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${book.isbn}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${book.printYear}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${book.readAlready}"/></td>
    <td><a href="<c:url value="/edit/${book.id}"/>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="<c:url value="/remove/${book.id}"/>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<%--</c:forEach>--%>
</table>


<h1>Add a Book</h1>

<c:url var="addAction" value="books/add"/>
<form:form action="${addAction}" method="post" commandName="book">
<table>
    <%--<c:if test="${!empty book}">--%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="id">
                    <spring:message text="id"/>
                </form:label>
                <form:input path="id"/>
            </td>
         <%--   <td>
                <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8" 
disabled="true"/>
                <form:hidden path="id"/>
            </td>--%>
        </tr>
    <%--</c:if>--%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="title">
                <spring:message text="title"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="title"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="description">
                <spring:message text="description"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="description"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="author">
                <spring:message text="author"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="author"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="isbn">
                <spring:message text="isbn"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="isbn"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="readAlready">
                <spring:message text="readAlready"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="readAlready"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="printYear">
                <spring:message text="printYear"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="printYear"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Результат:
[image: Результат]

Ссылка на гит: https://github.com/Ahdpei95/crud?files=1

Сильно не бейте:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, криво установлен был tomcat 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Я совсем не специалист в jsp, но что-то мне подсказывает, что вы в цикле завязались на переменной `b`:

```
<%--<c:forEach items="${listBooks}" var="b">--%>
```

А значит и обращаться теперь нужно к `b`, а не к `book`:

```
<td><c:out value="${b.id}"/></td>
```

Comment: Book это ещё один из объектов карты. Я хотел хоть одну запись вывести. С переменной foreach тоже самое выводит.